# Как в регулярных выражениях на C# написать, что температура может быть нулевой, но число не может начинаться с 0

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Надо написать проверку температуры через регулярные выражения. Я написал, но есть недочет. Температура может быть нулевой (например + 0 С), но она не может начинаться с 0 (- 09 С). Как решить эту проблему?

```cs
Regex temperatura = new Regex(@"^-?\W*\+?\W*\d+\s(C|F)$");
```

Comment: `Regex temperatura = new Regex(@"^-?\W*\+?\W*[1-9]\d*\s(C|F)$");`? А почему у вас тут везде `\W*`?

Comment: W/ - не алфавитно цифровой символ и * - предыдущий символ повторяется 0 или более раз

Comment: У вас в `- 09 С` кириллическая `С`. Я так понимаю, вам нужно проверить на наличие латинской `C`.

Comment: Там латинская стоит. Получается надо сделать так, чтобы температура + 0 C выводилась как правильная, а + 05 C как неправильная

Comment: [В `- 09 С` не латинская](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=-%2009%20%D0%A1). Не важно, я понял.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```cs
Regex temperatura = new Regex(@"^[+-]?\W*(?:[1-9]\d*|0)(?:[,.]\d+)?\W*[CF]\z", RegexOptions.ECMAScript);
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%2b-%5d%3f%5cW*%28%3f%3a%5b1-9%5d%5cd*%7c0%29%28%3f%3a%5b%2c.%5d%5cd%2b%29%3f%5cW*%5bCF%5d%5cr%3f%24&i=%2b+0+C%0d%0a-23+C%0d%0a%2b0%2c6+C%0d%0a-+09+C&o=m).

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `[+-]?` - необязательный `-` или `+`
- `\W*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от букв, цифр, соединительной пунктуации (например, `_`), а также большинства диакритических знаков
- `(?:[1-9]\d*|0)` - цифра от 1 до 9, за которой следует ноль и более цифр, или 0
- `(?:[,.]\d+)?` - необязательная последовательность точки или запятой, после которой идут одна и более цифр
- `[CF]` - символ `C` или `F`
- `\z` - конец строки.

Параметр `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` позволяет `\d` находить только те цифры, которые расположены в начале таблицы Юникода, ASCII.